# Non-existent collision detected with OnCollisionEnter()

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to make a sticky grenade by disabling its rigidbody upon collision, using `OnCollisionEnter()`. However, `OnCollisionEnter()` fires when there is clearly no collision happening, as you can see in this image :

[image]

This causes my grenade to stick in the air. I suspect this is due to a lack of synchronization between physics loop & rendering loop. Also, my standard "non-sticky" grenade uses the same model & is working finely.

I already tried the following :

- Verify that there are no other colliders which could cause my grenade
  to "stick in the air"
- Use `OnTriggerEnter()`  instead. The result is a little better but the problem is that it is fired too late, only once the grenade is inside an obstacle or an enemy.
- Add rigidbody & continuous collision detection to all objects
- Tweak PhysicsManager.DefaultContactOffset from 0.01 to 0.001, as suggested by Eliasar
- Switch from "PCM" to "Legacy Contacts Generation"

None of these worked so I'm feeling a little desperate. Thanks in advance for your help !

Code I use to stick the grenade upon collision :

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision c) {
   rigidbody.isKinematic = true;
   transform.parent = c.transform;
}
```

Comment: Have you done any `Debug.Log`'ing to see what GameObjects it's colliding with? Also, you might try commenting out the`transfrom.parent = c.transform` if you want it to stick right where it hits, otherwise you'll be moving it to the center of the object that it's colliding with.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. I did try some `Debug.Log` 'ing and the grenade is indeed colliding with the obstacle. I also tried commenting out the parenting line but it didn't help unfortunately.

Comment: Is your sticky grenade a child of another GameObject?

Comment: No it's not. Also the grenade is colliding correctly with enemies, so I suspect the problem would be on the side of the obtsacle rather than the grenade itself